# Can I have a rank column that only has the rank for a certain record?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

So i have the following select line

```
,RANK() OVER (Partition by sd.Last_Secondary_School_Provider_Key ORDER BY SUM([EFTS_Consumed]) DESC) AS Rank
```

that selects the rank fine, but I was wondering in this rank column can I just have the rank where `column2 = 'Auckland University of Tehcnology'`?

e.g. in the ranking, `'Auckland University of Tehcnology'` might come in as 4, can I just have all rows in the rank column then just come in as 4?

So for the following sample data I would want all records in the `'Rank'` column to calculate to 4 : https://i.stack.imgur.com/nr8Ii.jpg

Cheers :)

Comment: The question is a tad unclear, at least to me. Could you please share some sample data and the result you're trying to get for it?

Comment: Yes, you just need to put that clause into your where clause

Comment: @RodrigoGomes that wouldn't work, otherwise all rows in the `Provider` column would come in as `Auckland University of Technology`, please check my updated post for sample data

Comment: you can use a temporary table `declare @tempRankTable as TABLE ( /*Columns Definition*/ )` , then you insert your rank results into this table and you can retrieve just the rows you want it from this temp table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
;with sub as
(
    ... your query ...
)
, rnk as
(
select  top 1 [Rank]
from    sub
where   Last_Secondary_School_Provider_Key = 'Auckland University of Technology'
)
select      sub.col1,
            sub.col2,
            sub.col3,
            sub.col4, -- select all cols from sub except rank
            rnk.[Rank] -- and select rank from the rnk block
from        sub
 cross join rnk;
```